# What is the bus width in this case?

Tags: bus, decoder

Given the two 16-bit buses, D_0 and D_1, shown in the figure below, what is the bus width of the 2-input bus Y?

[image]

Comment: It could be anything depending on the context, and we don't know the context.

Comment: edited the question to say that the bus Y takes two inputs

Comment: @AliMustafa - Hi, If D_0 and D_1 are 16-bit buses, then the diagram is either simplified or misleading, as there isn't just one buffer gate on D_0 and one on D_1 if they are 16-bit buses. Either the diagram isn't showing all 16 buffer gates per bus (simplified) or the gate is on only 1 bit of each bus (misleading). That new information about bus Y taking "2 inputs" is still too vague IMHO. Can you include the *full* text of the question, with *all* context, please? Perhaps that will help clarify what the original question-writer intended. Thanks. (Are you sure the "serial-bus" tag applies?)

Comment: Unfortunately that was all of the information provided in the exercise. The correct answer was supposed to be one of the following three options: 1) 2 bits, 2) 16 bits, or 3) 32 bits. I have also removed the serial bus tag, because it was never specified in the exercise.

Comment: If that is from a book, then the only way is to read the book what that kind of diagram would mean, because by looking at that, any of those answers could be correct, although more likely the 16 and 32 bit ones.

Comment: Since this is homework, we don't give out answers; we do critique your work.  So, how do *you* understand bus structures to work?  With what you have been given, there is only one correct answer.  Note, however, that there is another correct answer that is not in your list.

Comment: I believe it must be 16 to fit the input from either of the two input buses. I don't think 32 makes sense, because then you could have just as well used D_0 and D_1 directly. Is my reasoning wrong? Also, could you please tell me what the other correct answer is?